# Complete the Matrix

Tags: matrices

The eigenvectors of A (corresponding to the eigenvalue 2) = \begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 2  \\
    -1 & 4 \\
    \end{bmatrix}
can be solved by solving the matrix equation:

[image]

Here is my working:
[image]

My answers were $4$ and $-1/2$ which were apparently wrong, though I am wondering if I made a typo when I put in $-1/2$ (I am unable to check further).

Comment: Please include *all* the steps you took. Also what is the original matrix $A.$

Comment: A is posted in the question after the =, so A is (1, 2, -1, 4).

Comment: Oh I didn't see that from the way you typed the question. But still it would be good if you include all your steps so someone can see where it went wrong, if it did.

Comment: Added working..

Comment: I have closed your question for "lacking context".  More specifically, you have included vital information about your question in images.  Images are bandwidth intensive (a problem for some mobile users, particularly in parts of the world with poor internet infrastructure), less searchable, and inaccessible to people who access the site using screenreaders.  Please read the [MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/) and use the information there to format your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know where the matrix $\begin{pmatrix} 4 & -2 \\ 1 & -1/2 \end{pmatrix}$ comes from.

The way I have seen it done is that $\begin{pmatrix} x \\ y \end{pmatrix}$ is a $\lambda$-eigenvector if

$\begin{pmatrix} 1-\lambda & 2 \\ -1 & 4-\lambda \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} x \\ y \end{pmatrix}= \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}$.

So when $\lambda = 2$ we want:

$\begin{pmatrix} -1 & 2 \\ -1  & 2 \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} x \\ y \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}$.

Of course $\begin{pmatrix} -1 & 2 \\ -1  & 2 \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} x \\ y \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} -x+2y \\ -x+2y \end{pmatrix}$, so the vector works when $x=2y$.

So we want vectors $\begin{pmatrix} 2y \\ y \end{pmatrix}$ with $y\neq 0$.